# Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher crash

Tags: android, activityresultcontracts

I have registered launcher before activity get started but some times when launch is called on listener it gets crashed and reason is mentioned below

Sometimes I am getting this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher with contract j.c@ab78423 and input Intent You must ensure the ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch().
```

any solution?

I am following below approach :

1. Creating launcher variable for activityResultLauncher before activity is created

private var launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
// handling result
}

2. And launching this after activity is created by using below method:
   launcher.launch()

Comment: Post the code you write that you suspect to be the cause of the error you mentioned.